# Finding and parsing the where clause in a method that has a LINQ expression for a parameter

Tags: .net, linq, expression-trees

I have the following method:

```
public AgentContact GetAgentContacts(Expression<Func<AgentContact, bool>> predicate)
{ 
    return _db.AgentContacts.Where(predicate).First();
}
```

That I call with the following:

```
var agentcontacts = _rep.GetAgentContacts(agent => agent.AGENTID == id);
```

I have never looked into parsing out the expression tree. What I need to do is verify that has the required Entity framework's domain model database table column names have been used. Which in this case is "AGENTID". To extend this, I need the example to be able to parse for a number of database column names as in the lambda expression for this call:

```
var busAddress = _rep.GetBusAddresses(ba=>ba.BUSID==id && ba.ADDRESS_TYPE == addressTyp);
if (busAddress.Any())
{ 
    return View(busAddress.First());
}
```

which will look for "BUSID" and "ADDRESS_TYPE". All this is to find out if the expression is using the primary key for the table being queried. I have a requirement to use existing stored procedures when using the primary key.

Any help or direction to resources would truly be helpful.

**============== Additional requirement ======================
As a follow on to this question, how would I code to make sure that the expression contains only the public properties of the Entity?**

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question, but `Enumerable.First` also takes a predicate, so you can replace `_db.AgentContacts.Where(predicate).First();` with `_db.AgentContacts.First(predicate);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an `Expression` and you want to find out if a specific property is accessed in that expression. To find that out, you can use [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx): override its `VisitMember()` and in it compare the member in the expression with the member you're looking for.

The whole code could look something like this:

```
public class ExpressionPropertyFinder<T>
{
    private readonly ExpressionPropertyFinderVisitor m_visitor;

    private ExpressionPropertyFinder(MemberInfo member)
    {
        m_visitor = new ExpressionPropertyFinderVisitor(member);
    }

    // constructor can't be generic
    public static ExpressionPropertyFinder<T> Create<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return new ExpressionPropertyFinder<T>(
            ((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member);
    }

    public bool IsMemberAccessed(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return m_visitor.IsMemberAccessed(expression);
    }
}

class ExpressionPropertyFinderVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly MemberInfo m_member;

    private bool m_found;

    public ExpressionPropertyFinderVisitor(MemberInfo member)
    {
        m_member = member;
    }

    public bool IsMemberAccessed(Expression expression)
    {
        m_found = false;
        Visit(expression);
        return m_found;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member == m_member)
            m_found = true;

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
var finder = ExpressionPropertyFinder<Entity>.Create(e => e.Id);

finder.IsMemberAccessed(e => e.Id == 42) // true
finder.IsMemberAccessed(e => e.Name == "foo") // false
finder.IsMemberAccessed(e => e.Id == 42 && e.Name == "foo") // true
```